# Removing A Specific Line From A File

Tags: php, text

I have a text file like this:

```html
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I want to remove specific lines which numbers are in an array like this:

```html
$myfile='txt.txt';
$remove=array(1,3,6,7,10);
//wanna remove these lines
```

So I tried this code but It didn't work and It just doubles the text and ruins everything:

```html
<?php
$myfile='txt.txt';
$remove=array(1,3,5,7,10);
$lines=file($myfile);
$countline=sizeof($lines);
$data=file_get_contents($myfile);
for ($i=0; $i < $countline+1; $i++) { 
 if (in_array($i, $remove)) {
$editeddata=str_replace($lines[$i], "", $data);
 $removeline = file_put_contents($myfile, $editeddata.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

 }
}
?>
```

I couldn't use ((for)) properly and I think it will just ruin the text because it deletes lines one after another have been deleted and it changes the order so I should have a code to remove them all at once. 
And please don't give a code to just replace numbers because the main text file is not only numbers and contains word,etc...

Thanks A lot!

Comment: You're reading and writing the file at the same time. For such a short file just read the whole file into an array, close the file, do whatever you need to do, than write the transformed array to the file.

Comment: Why did you use `FILE_APPEND` if you don't want to append the changed data?

Comment: Actually the main text is not a short file.It has more than 2000 lines and I don't have any ideas how to control and remove lines from that file.

Comment: apokryfos oh my mistake.but even without using that, the text will be ruined again because ((for)) removes one after another

Comment: I'm not sure why people were down-voting this - it shows a demonstrated effort at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the file twice (with `file` and `file_get_contents`), which I think is confusing the later code. You have everything you need with the first call - an array of all the lines in the file. You're also using `str_replace` to remove the content, which seems a bit dangerous if any of the content is repeated.

I'd refactor this to simply filter the array of lines based on their line-number, then write it back to the file in a single operation:

```
$myfile = 'txt.txt';
$remove = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10];

// Read file into memory
$lines = file($myfile);

// Filter lines based on line number (+1 because the array is zero-indexed)
$lines = array_filter($lines, function($lineNumber) use ($remove) {
    return !in_array($lineNumber + 1, $remove);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

// Re-assemble the output (the lines already have a line-break at the end)
$output = implode('', $lines);

// Write back to file
file_put_contents($myfile, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file fits in memory then you can do the simple:

```
$myfile='txt.txt';
$remove=array(1,3,6,7,10);
file_put_contents($myfile, implode(PHP_EOL,array_diff($file($myfile,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), $remove)));
```

Note: Because it's a bit ambiguous whether `$remove` has the content or the lines you want to remove, the above code removes the content . If you want to remove lines change `array_diff($file($myfile,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), $remove)` to `array_diff_keys($file($myfile,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), array_flip($remove))`

If your file is large then you need to resort to some sort of streaming. I suggest against reading and writing to the same file and doing something like:

```
$myfile='txt.txt';    
$remove=array(1,3,6,7,10);
$h = fopen($myfile,"r");
$tmp = fopen($myfile.".tmp", "w");
while (($line = fgets($h)) !== false) {
      if (!in_array(rtrim($line, PHP_EOL), $remove)) {
          fwrite($tmp, $line);
      }
}
fclose($h);
fclose($tmp);
unlink($myfile);
rename($myfile.".tmp", $myfile);
```

Comment: Thanks mate but your second code has some problems.The temp file couldn't be renamed because it was being used by another process and it also has a problem in ((fgets)) that says fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given.

Comment: @Cr3diT0r it had a couple of mistakes, should work now

Comment: Thank u it works fine! Both you and iainn's codes are working fine! p.s: I can't up vote you because of reputations limits sry <3